# Email has stopped message once per day on Android Lollipop version 5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, email, crashes, stock-email-app

I have an issue on Samsung Galaxy S5 where I get a `Email has stopped` message at least once per day.

I have updated to the latest OS - I'm on Android Lollipop version 5 and I have tried deleting the mailbox and recreating it.

I've also tried rebooting the phone and starting and stopping the mail application (and clearing the cache).

I'm using the default mail app. Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are another one or two topics on this over at XDA-developers, and I haven't been able to find a solution or cause for the problem. I suggest you use the `Gmail` app, because it has great support for Emails that are "non-google". The most obvious (however I could be wrong) answer to this is a bug in the Samsung Email app (But if you're on Lollipop you should really consider using the `Gmail` app instead!).

If you really insist on using the Samsung app for Email, try clearing your `system cache` (from recovery), it seems to do a lot of fixing in the Android world. Note that your next boot *might* be a little (and by that I mean 10-20 minutes) longer then normal, as it is recreating the `dalvik cache`

Comment: Neat, I didn't realise the Gmail app supports non-Gmail accounts. I'll try that. The mailbox is an AOL one if that has any significance.

Comment: [Gmail support link on non-google emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6078445?hl=en). I believe Gmail has supported the AOL Email type since version 5.x of the app. You should have no problem with this on an S5